# Trying to close a window using window.close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Trying to close a window if user is inactive, window.close() works on Edge but doesn't work on Chrome (Version 69.0.3497.81)

I am using react-idle-timer and trying to close the window if the user is idle for a specific duration

window.open('','_self','');
window.top.close();

Comment: When opening a window, set a reference to it and use that reference to close it. (i.e. `let newWin = window.open(); newWin.close()`.

Comment: Added as below:

let newWin = window.open('','_parent','');
newWin.close();

 Still doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox, works on edge. 

trying to close the window upon no activity from the user and I am using react-idle-timer to monitor that and close the window after 
certain timeout

 _onIdle () {
   console.log('user is idle');
    console.log('last active',this.idleTimer.getLastActiveTime());
    this.setState({ isIdle: true });
    let newWin = window.open('','_parent','');
    newWin.close();
  }